# PS1 Style Formatting

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to make my bash profile look cool, and I outright stole this example that was posted on the internet (can't remember where though; I claim no credit for it). I managed to get all of the different quirks I wanted to work and got all of the color and syntax codes working on my Arch box, but on my MacBook, the terminal app shows this huge space between the bracket and the number of files in the pwd. I would greatly appreciate any help in making it look pretty since it kind of bums me out to look at that space.[image: PS1 prompt]

I have included my PS1 below:

```
export PS1="┌─[\`if [ \$? = 0 ]; then echo \[\e[32m\]✔\[\e[0m\]; else echo \[\e[31m\]✘\[\e[0m\]; fi\`]───[\[\e[01;49;39m\]\u\[\e[00m\]\[\e[01;49;39m\]\[\e[00m\]]───[\[\e[1;49;39m\]\W\[\e[0m\]]───[\[\e[1;49;39m\]\$(ls | wc -l) files, \$(ls -lah | grep -m 1 total | sed 's/total //')\[\e[0m\]]\n└───▶ "
```

Comment: This isn't really a programming issue. That said, it's `wc -l` that's inserting the spaces. Try replacing that with `sed -ne '\$='`, or better yet, replace that whole block with something like this, to avoid calling subshells and pipe commands so much: `\$(a=(*); printf '%d files, ' "\${#a[@]}"; read x y < <(ls -lah); echo \$y) bytes`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't really know where else to ask it. I'll try this out.